# How to re-create the symmetric key on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, encryption, amazon-rds

We have some column encrypted by symmetric key. Now we want to upload our database to Amazon RDS (SQL Server).

Can we do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: maybe.

If you created the key with the KEY_SOURCE argument when you created the key and you have the value that you specified at creation time, then you'd just issue the same `create symmetric key` statement again in RDS and you should have the same key as in your source.

If you didn't do that, then no. It doesn't appear that there is something like `backup symmetric key`.